# What's the noun of the verb “aller”?

Tags: substantivation

What's the noun corresponding to the verb *aller*?

Should we say: “*une allure*”, or what?

Comment: What is it in english?

Comment: @mouviciel: "Going", as in "When the going gets tough, the tough get going".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are various substantives.

**allée** : narrow passage, usually pedestrian, between two walls or rows of trees ; it used to mean also "the fact of aller", but survives only in "les allées et venues" (= comings and goings)

**aller** : usually a ticket (bus, train, plane) ; aller simple (a single), aller et retour (a return) ; it used to be "the fact of aller", but survives only in "le pis-aller" (= stopgap)

**allure** :

a)  = speed or pace ; "la voiture roulait à vive allure" = *the car was running fast*

b)  = walk, gait ; "son allure était hésitante" = *his walk was hesitant/not sure*

c)  = appearance ; "il avait mauvaise allure" = *He had a bad appearance or his look was not engaging.*

d)  = ways ; "il choque par sa liberté d'allure" = *his unconventional behaviour is shocking ou He shocks by his liberty of ways.*

Comment: **allant** is also derived from *ALLER*, *avoir de l'allant* 'to be energetic'

Comment: Allure  meaning speed is a very new meaning for the term. Allure traditionally means the way you make yourself attractive.

Answer (score 5):

I'd say it's simply *un aller*, like in *un aller-retour* or *un aller simple*.

Answer (score 2):

Le sens le plus conforme, et utilisable dans presque tous les cas est:

> Un déplacement.

Le terme suivant correspond à une partie de l'action d'aller:

> Un mouvement.

Le terme suivant correspond à la fois au déplacement (l'action), et au tracé (sur une carte par exemple):

> Un trajet, un parcours.

Lorsque le déplacement est plutôt important ou exceptionnel, ou est **précisé**, on peut employer:

> Un aller (et un aller-retour). Un aller pour l'enfer, un aller simple.

**On dit plus souvent (et notamment lorsque le déplacement est banal):**

> La venue, votre venue.

*venue* est le substantif rattaché à *venir*, c'est le résultat final qui paraît le plus important.

Lorsqu'il est répétitif (sans être nécessairement exceptionnel):

> Vos allers.
>
> Vos allées et venues.

Le terme aller est aussi fréquemment lié aux transports commerciaux (bus, avions, trains, ...) et tickets (voir aller-retour);

**Le terme allure n'a pas ce sens**, et se rattache à la **vitesse** (à vive allure, à petite allure, à toute allure), ou à la **manière**, et par extension à l'**aspect**. voir 
http://www.littre.org/definition/allure

http://cnrtl.fr/definition/allure

et l'étymologie : http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/allure

Comment: +1 for mentioning "parcours" which at least goes well with "parcourir." (please see my comment under Charlie's answer)

Comment: @comethapaxd'ajax - merci, car impossible de faire un permalien sur l'atilf

Answer (score 1):

Dans le sens *go/no go* à propos de la décision ou non de démarrer un projet, on peut dire **feu vert**: *J'ai obtenu le feu vert de ma hiérarchie pour réaliser cette action*.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider **To Go** the verb you are trying to translate as a gerundive, then there is no specific translation of **Going** into French, as usual between Germanic and Romanic languages. This is a case by case.

How would you translate "When the going gets tough, the tough gets going"? Good luck with that one.

**Allure** is not a derivative of **Aller**, but instead of a Germanic term for **To Lure** with the prefix **ad** meaning towards oneself. It therefore defines how you make yourself attractive, not how you are going around.

Comment: +1 for the interesting suggestion/challenge to find a more literal translation of "When **the going** gets tough ..." that captures **the going**  better than the standard one ("Quand **les choses** se corsent, les durs s'y mettent"). How about: "Quand **le parcours** devient dur, les durs **parcourent**!"?

Comment: The [TLFi](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/allure) disagrees with your etymology making it a word derived from *ALLER* with the suffix *ure* (*moisissure, foulure, bavure, déchirure, gravure, etc.*).

Comment: I did specifically state exactly the same thing, but whatever, I guess.

Answer (score -1):

You could also use "une promenade", depending on what you want to express.